# i need to click unordered links in the below URL using selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

In the below URL i need to click the message icon links which containing 'svg' tags inside it.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898656817301687

for that iam using below code

```
    lenoftags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="author size-m workspace-trigger"]//*[local-name()="svg"]')
    tagcount = len(lenoftags)
    newcount = range(1, tagcount)
    if len(lenoftags) == 0:
        driver.back()
    elif len(lenoftags) >= 1:
        for jj in newcount:
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="author size-m workspace-trigger"][%d]//*[local-name()="svg"]'%jj).click()
            except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="author size-m workspace-trigger"]//*[local-name()="svg"]').click()
                except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, WebDriverException):
                    continue
        driver.back()
        driver.back()
    else:
        driver.back()
```

the code is working when the links in order but in above URL it is clicking only first link.
any one please resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid implementing extra logic. Try below instead:

```
tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "author")]//*[local-name()="svg"]')
if tags:
    # Links found
    for tag in tags:
        tag.click()
else:
    # Links not found
    # Do something else
```